# Font Not Changing in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie here and trying to build a basic website on my computer but for some reason, the font I want to use isn't changing. My HTML and css are in the correct folder and I'm pretty sure it's linked correctly. I tried `!important` but that didn't change anything. I'm not seeing any spelling errors. I'm not sure where my code is wrong. pls help!

HTML:

```
 <html>

  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width">
   <meta name="author" content="CCN">
   <title>Acme Web Design | Welcome </title>
   <link rel="sylesheet" href="style.css"> 
  </head>

<body>
 <header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
         <h1> Acme Web Design</h1>
     </div>
     <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html"> About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html"> Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
  </header>`<section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
        <h1> Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce mattis, mauris eget bibendum bibendum, diam urna interdum nisl, quis auctor est urna sed felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris eget imperdiet nisi. </p>
    </div>
 </section>

 <section id="newsletter">
    <div class="container">
        <h1> Subscribe To Our Newsletter</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email...">
            <button type="submit" class="button_1"> Subscribe</button>
        </form>
    </div>
 </section>

 <section id="boxes">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="./img/logo_html.png" >
          <h3> HTML 5 Markup</h3>  
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
    </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="./img/logo_css.png" >
            <h3> CSS3 Styling</h3>  
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        </div>
          <div class="box">
            <img src="./img/logo_brush.png" >
            <h3> Graphic Design</h3>  
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          </div>
  </section>

 <footer>
    <p> Acme Web Design, Copyright &copy; 2017 </p>
  </footer>
```

`

css:

```
body{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Can you inspect the element in your browser and see if anything is overwriting `font-family`

Comment: Perhaps a caching issue. Try clearing cache via dev tools.

Comment: If it's linked perfectly, then you can inspect the element for CSS. If the changes do not appear, try again after clearing cache.

Comment: add this line just before opening of body 
    `<style>body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;} </style>`

Comment: Typo in `rel="sylesheet"`

Comment: change your link rel you have a typo inside, change sylesheet to stylesheet and you're done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a spelling error, actually:

```
<link rel="sylesheet" href="style.css">
```

It should be "stylesheet". Once you fix this, it will work.